# when am running my testscript through selenium if screen get locks my testcases geting failed

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, regression

in my organiztaion automaticaly pc screen wil get lock from a server if idle when am running my scripts also pc getting lock and also if i switch to some other browser when running a scripts my testcases getting failed.

But Even a in a Eclipse IDE my test suite will be running as usual dono how to run my automation suite please anybody have a idea to deal with it.let me know. thank u in advance**

Comment: please help me on this anybody i stuck from fewdays on this isssue..

Comment: please run in headless mode.

Comment: btt issue here is i want to run a test only in a IE browser how to run a Headless in ie Browser @Abishek_Mishra .

Comment: hi please anybody Known about this issue please help me frndz..@@thank u.